# Why is List.reduce necessary in this newbie example?

Tags: f#

Playing around with F#, I am confused with the following behavior. When `List.reduce (>>)` is commented out,  there is the error

```
defaultLabel |> showRainbow
----------------^^^^^^^^^^^
This expression was expected to have type
    CoolLabel -> 'a    
but here has type
    (CoolLabel -> CoolLabel) list
```

in this example boiled down from http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/conciseness-functions-as-building-blocks/ :

```
// create an underlying type
type CoolLabel = {
    label : string; 
}    

let defaultLabel = 
    {label="";}

let setLabel msg label = 
   {label with CoolLabel.label = msg}

let rainbow =
    ["red";"orange";"yellow";"green";"blue";"indigo";"violet"]

let showRainbow = 
    rainbow
    |> List.map setLabel 
    |> List.reduce (>>)

// test the showRainbow function
defaultLabel |> showRainbow
```

When `List.reduce (>>)` is removed, I would think that showRainbow should return a list of CoolLabel, and the compiler would be cool with everything.

Edit -> (Ignore this sentence, because the answer below changed my understanding.): "As an aside, I get that List.reduce (>>) would return the last CoolLabel from the list."

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing the line with `List.reduce (>>)` changes the type of `showRainbow` and so you get something that is not a function and so the pipelining operator cannot call it with `defaultLabel` as an argument.

In the original program, the type of `showRainbow` is a function that turns one `CoolLabel` into another:

```
val showRainbow : (CoolLabel -> CoolLabel)
```

If you remove the line, you get a *list* of functions:

```
val showRainbow : (CoolLabel -> CoolLabel) list
```

This example is not using functions in a trivial way, so let me explain a bit what is acutally going on. We start with `rainbow` which is a list of colors. Next, `rainbow |> List.map setLabel` turns the list of *colors* into a list of *functions*. You can read this as:

```
rainbow |> List.map (fun color -> setLabel color)
```

But, `setLabel` takes *two* arguments. Here we specify just the first one, so the result is a function that expects `CoolLabel` and changes its color to the current color of the rainbow.

Once you have the list of functions, `List.reduce (>>)` composes them - it builds a new function that calls all of them on the input it receives. So the result is essentially a function:

```
let resultingFunction input = 
  setLabel "violet" (setLabel "indigo" (setLabel "blue" ( ... (input)))))
```

Now you can see why this returns a label with violet - it changes the color of `defaultLabel` to red, then to orange, then to yellow, etc. and finally to indigo and then to violet!

If you change `setLabel` so that it does not ignore the original color, but perhaps combines them (by appending strings) then you will see how the `setLabel` function was called on all colors:

```
let setLabel msg label = 
  { label with CoolLabel.label = label.label + " " + msg }
```

The result will be:

```
> defaultLabel |> showRainbow;;
val it : CoolLabel = {label = " red orange yellow green blue indigo violet";}
```